# UNIX timestamp js

Tags: javascript, unixtimestamp

Подскажите пожалуйста по конвертации времени. Данный код возвращает количество секунд прошедших со старта.
Как вывести количество минут, которое прошло со старта?

```js
setInterval(function() {
 var start = 1581428734;
 var unix_sec = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
 var sec = unix_sec-start;

 console.log(":"+sec);
}, 1000);
```

Нужно получить время в формате `5:25`.

Comment: разделить на 60, не?

Comment: @humster_spb имеется ввиду что прошло 1 минута 25 секунд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно:

```js
setInterval(function() {
   var start = 1581428734;
   var unix_sec = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
   var min = Math.round((unix_sec-start)/60)%60;
   var sec = (unix_sec-start)%60;

   console.log("min:"+min+" sec:"+sec);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.